# DataGridView+ сторонний контрол

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, devexpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли увязать сторонний контролл с `DatagridView`? В частности, `RatingControl` от `DevExpress`. Пример ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: используйте datatemplate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На просторах большого [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) был найден похожий на ваш [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19914880/5275890) и довольно не плохой [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19924829/5275890). Звучит вопрос так: *«Using a custom control in a DataGridView»* (Использование настраиваемого элемента управления в DataGridView). Собственно говоря, ссылка на источник: [Using a custom control in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19924829/5275890) и перевод ответа на русский язык:

Для начала необходимо вычислить общее количество ячеек отображения, и вам необходим список `List<YourControl>` чтобы хранить все необходимые элементы управления. Эти элементы управления должны иметь свой `DataGridView` как и их `Parent`. Количество этих элементов должно быть равно количеству отображаемых ячеек. Затем в обработчике события `CellPainting` вы должны обновить расположение всех элементов управления в списке. В обработчика события `CellPainting` добавим код обновления, потому что всякий раз, когда значение ячейки и границы обновляются, то `CellPainting` выполнится и обновит средства управления `Location`. Этот процесс немного сложнее, но это работает. Вы можете связать каждый элемент управления с каждой ячейкой с помощью свойства `reference` , у такого элемента как `Tag` свойство.

Подход. Вам просто нужно создать пользовательский `DataGridViewCell` используемый в качестве `CellTemplate` для обычного `DataGridViewColumn`. Далее  довольно много кода:

```
public class DataGridViewRatingColumn : DataGridViewColumn {
    public DataGridViewRatingColumn() : base(new DataGridViewRatingCell()) {
        base.ReadOnly = true;
        RatedStarColor = Color.Green;
        GrayStarColor = Color.LightGray;
        StarScale = 1;            
    }
    bool readOnly;
    public new bool ReadOnly
    {
        get {
            return readOnly;
        }
        set {
            readOnly = value;                
        }
    }
    Color ratedStarColor;
    Color grayStarColor;
    float starScale;
    public Color RatedStarColor {
        get { return ratedStarColor; }
        set {
            if (ratedStarColor != value) {
                ratedStarColor = value;
                if (DataGridView != null) DataGridView.InvalidateColumn(Index);
            }
        }
    }
    public Color GrayStarColor
    {
        get { return grayStarColor; }
        set {
            if (grayStarColor != value){
                grayStarColor = value;
                if(DataGridView != null) DataGridView.InvalidateColumn(Index);
            }
        }
    }
    public float StarScale {
        get { return starScale; }
        set {
            if (starScale != value) {
                starScale = value;
                DataGridViewRatingCell.UpdateBrushes(value);
                if (DataGridView != null) DataGridView.InvalidateColumn(Index);
            }
        }
    }
}    
public class DataGridViewRatingCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell {
    static DataGridViewRatingCell() {
        //Init star            
        List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
        bool largeArc = true;
        R = 10;
        r = 4;
        center = new Point(R, R);
        for (float alpha = 90; alpha <= 414; alpha += 36)
        {
            int d = largeArc ? R : r;
            double radAlpha = alpha * Math.PI / 180;
            float x = (float)(d * Math.Cos(radAlpha));
            float y = (float)(d * Math.Sin(radAlpha));
            points.Add(new PointF(center.X + x, center.Y + y));
            largeArc = !largeArc;
        }
        star.AddPolygon(points.ToArray());
        star.Transform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, center.Y * 2));             
        //Init stars
        UpdateBrushes(1);                   
    }
    public DataGridViewRatingCell() {
        ValueType = typeof(int);
        ratedStarColor = Color.Green;
        grayStarColor = Color.LightGray;
        starScale = 1;
        UseColumnStarColor = true;
        UseColumnStarScale = true;            
    }                
    public override object DefaultNewRowValue {
        get {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    internal static void UpdateBrushes(float scale) {
        int space = 2*R;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (stars[i] != null) stars[i].Dispose();
            stars[i] = (GraphicsPath)star.Clone();
            stars[i].Transform(new Matrix(scale, 0, 0, scale, space * i * scale, 0));                
            brushes[i] = CreateBrush(new RectangleF(center.X - R + space * i * scale, center.Y - R, R * 2 * scale, R * 2 * scale));
        }
    }
    private static LinearGradientBrush CreateBrush(RectangleF bounds)
    {
        var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(bounds,Color.White, Color.Yellow, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal);
        ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
        Color c = Color.Green;
        Color lightColor = Color.White;
        cb.Colors = new Color[] { c, c, lightColor, c, c };
        cb.Positions = new float[] { 0, 0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f, 1 };
        brush.InterpolationColors = cb;            
        return brush;
    }
    private void AdjustBrushColors(LinearGradientBrush brush, Color baseColor, Color lightColor)
    {
        //Note how we adjust the colors, using brush.InterpolationColors directly won't work.
        ColorBlend cb = brush.InterpolationColors;
        cb.Colors = new Color[] { baseColor, baseColor, lightColor, baseColor, baseColor };
        brush.InterpolationColors = cb;
    }        
    static GraphicsPath star = new GraphicsPath();
    static GraphicsPath[] stars = new GraphicsPath[5];
    static LinearGradientBrush[] brushes = new LinearGradientBrush[5];
    static Point center;
    static int R, r;
    int currentValue = -1;
    bool mouseOver;
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, 
        int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, 
        string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue,
            errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);             
        if (rowIndex == RowIndex && (paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground) != 0) {
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            if(Value != null) Value = Math.Min(Math.Max(0, (int)Value), 5);
            if (!mouseOver) currentValue = (int)(Value ?? 0);  
            PaintStars(graphics, cellBounds, 0, currentValue, true);
            PaintStars(graphics, cellBounds, currentValue, 5 - currentValue, false);
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.Default;             
        }
    }
    protected override void OnMouseMove(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (!mouseOver) mouseOver = true;
        if (IsReadOnly()) return;
        var lastStar = stars.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                            .LastOrDefault(x => x.x.IsVisible(e.Location));
        if (lastStar != null) {
            currentValue = lastStar.i + 1;                
            DataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }
        else if(RowIndex > -1) {
            currentValue = (int)(Value ?? 0);
            DataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
        DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
    }        
    protected override void OnClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        base.OnClick(e);
        if (IsReadOnly()) return;
        Value = currentValue == 1 && (int?) Value == 1 ? 0 : currentValue;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(int rowIndex) {
        base.OnMouseLeave(rowIndex);
        mouseOver = false;
        if (IsReadOnly()) return;
        if (rowIndex == RowIndex) {
            currentValue = (int)(Value ?? 0);
            DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
        }            
    }        
    private bool IsReadOnly() {
        var col = OwningColumn as DataGridViewRatingColumn;
        return col != null ? col.ReadOnly : false;
    }
    private void PaintStars(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, int startIndex, int count, bool rated) {
        GraphicsState gs = g.Save();
       g.TranslateTransform(bounds.Left, bounds.Top);           
        var col = OwningColumn as DataGridViewRatingColumn;
        Color ratedColor = col == null ? Color.Yellow :
            UseColumnStarColor ? col.RatedStarColor : RatedStarColor;
        Color grayColor = col == null ? Color.LightGray :
            UseColumnStarColor ? col.GrayStarColor : GrayStarColor;
        float starScale = col == null ? 1 :
            UseColumnStarScale ? col.StarScale : StarScale;
        UpdateBrushes(starScale);
       for(int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + count; i++) {
           AdjustBrushColors(brushes[i], rated ? ratedColor : grayColor, rated ? Color.White : grayColor);
           g.FillPath(brushes[i], stars[i]);
           //g.DrawPath(Pens.Green, stars[i]);
       }
       g.Restore(gs);
    }        
    Color ratedStarColor;
    Color grayStarColor;
    float starScale;
    public Color RatedStarColor {
        get { return ratedStarColor; }
        set {
            if (ratedStarColor != value) {
                ratedStarColor = value;
                var col = OwningColumn as DataGridViewRatingColumn;
                if (col != null && col.RatedStarColor != value) {
                    UseColumnStarColor = false;
                    DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public Color GrayStarColor {
        get { return grayStarColor; }
        set {
            if (grayStarColor != value) {
                grayStarColor = value;
                var col = OwningColumn as DataGridViewRatingColumn;
                if (col != null && col.GrayStarColor != value) {
                    UseColumnStarColor = false;
                    DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Change the star size via scaling factor (default by 1)
    public float StarScale {
        get { return starScale; }
        set {
            if (starScale != value) {
                starScale = value;
                var col = OwningColumn as DataGridViewRatingColumn;
                if (col != null && col.StarScale != value) {
                    UseColumnStarScale = false;                        
                    DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public bool UseColumnStarColor { get; set; }
    public bool UseColumnStarScale { get; set; }
}
```

**Примечания:** два класса `DataGridViewRatingColumn` и `DataGridViewRatingCell` должны быть размещены в одном и том же файле, потому что внутри объявлен статический метод `UpdateBrushes` в `DataGridViewRatingCell` используемый в классе `DataGridViewRatingColumn`. Можно изменить модификатор доступа, если нужно разместить их в отдельных файлах. Посмотрите на предоставленные классы, свойства и методы - их названия говорят сами за себя. Их можно использовать,
 чтобы настроить внешний вид контрола (звезд). Пример кода, показывающий использование:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewRatingColumn(){
     // свойства DataGridViewRatingColumn можно инициализировать здесь...
});

// Чтобы изменить ReadOnly, которое позволяет пользователю писать или нет, вам нужно
// сначала преобразовать столбец в DataGridViewRatingColumn, это поведение вызвано 
// ненормальным поведением переопределения ReadOnly (поэтому пришлось использовать новый).
((DataGridViewRatingColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[0]).ReadOnly = true; (default by false)

// также вы должны включить DoubleBuffered в DataGridView для устранения мерцания
typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
  .SetValue(dataGridView1, true, null);
```

Возможно перевод не идеален, поэтому заранее прошу прощения. Главное, что суть ответа ясна и все довольно подробно изложено. Мелкие комментарии в коде переводить не стал.